# Optimal Control: How to find the cost function from the given dynamics?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

Consider the growth equation:  $x'(t)=tu(t)$ , with $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)=1$, and with the cost function: $J= \int_0^1 u^2(t) dt$.

I'm wondering how to find the expression $ u^2(t)$ that is inside of the integral?

Comment: Is it "find" or "minimize" the cost function?

Comment: My question is how to find the expression inside of integral?

Comment: What is $u$? Is it a function of $x$ and/or $t$? Are you trying to find the $u$ which minimizes $J$?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 My question is how to find the formula that is inside of the integral

Comment: The function $u$ is the control: usually one find $u$ to minimise the cost function.

Comment: @mlc I know that the cost functional is. $J=\int_0^1 \phi (x'(t),x(t),u(t))dt$, then my question is why $\phi (x'(t),x(t),u(t))$ is equal to $u^2(t)$

Answer (score 2):

The cost function $J$ is given with the problem, it is the objective function you are trying to minimize. The constraint on $u$ is that the BVP given has a solution. Integrating, we get that $x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t su(s)ds = \int_0^t su(s)ds$, so $x(1) = \int_0^1 tu(t)dt = 1$. This restricts the set of functions $u(t)$ that we have to choose from to minimize the objective $J$. In the unconstrained case, it's clear that the minimum of $J$ is $0$, achieved when $u(t)\equiv 0$. However, since this doesn't satisfy the constraint ($\int_0^1 t\cdot 0 dt = 0 \neq 1$), it is not a solution.

Comment: You said "The cost function J is given with the problem", but  if only they give me $x′(t)=tu(t)$, with respective initial conditions, how do you find a cost functional?

Comment: That's just a BVP. There is no inherent cost associated with it. For any $u(t)$ such that $\int_0^1 tu(t)dt = 1$, it has the unique solution $x(t) = \int_0^t su(s)ds$. The cost function is usually chosen based on the model. There may be some cost associated to creating the $u$ "forcing", changing the forcing, or just keeping the system going for a certain amount of time. That cost gets written (usually approximated) as the cost functional. Ideally we'd like to keep cost at a minimum while still achieving the desired effect (the BVP has a solution), hence the problem given.

Comment: You said "The cost function is usually chosen according to the model" How is that choice made in this case? I continue without understanding why the functional cost $ J $ is that way and how do you get that "formula" $\int_0^1 u^2(t) dt$

Comment: In this case there is no model, at least not from what you've shown us. It is a contrived problem where someone came up with the ODE, the boundary values, and the cost function. The model is the real life situation you are trying to approximate with this system, which is not given here. You need to know what the variables represent in order to come up with a cost function on your own. Otherwise, you can just accept it as given along with all the other information about the problem. It is completely possible to have the same BVP with any cost function, so there's no point in worrying about it.